# Explain the behaviour of >= and <= operators in the following case

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators

```
function foo(){
console.log( function(){return 1} <= function(){return 1} );
}
foo();
```

The above code prints "true". It prints true for both <= and >= , For all other operators it is "false".

What trick going on here?

Comment: @Sterling I don't think that function's toString() operator is being called because the following return false: `function(){return 1} == function(){return 1}`

Comment: @Dmitri So javascript has different conversion policy for operands in case of >=,<- and a different policy for others??

Comment: Yes, the evaluation for `==` and `===` is different than `<=`, `>=`, `>`, `<`, especially on instances comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not comparing the returned `1`, it's comparing the `functions`. When you run an operator on a function, it implicitly calls `toString`.

As for `==`, Dmitri explained it well enough that `toString` is not being called, but it runs an object comparison, which will be false because 2 different objects are never the same.

Here is the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators) On relational operators, which explains how it operates with comparison operations. With objects, `instanceOf` is used.

Comment: That seems plausible, but seems weird for JS. Can you include the spec sections that describe this?

Answer (score 2):

`function(){return 1} <= function(){return 1}` transforms the functions to a primitive. A function transformed to a primitive evaluates to it's code in a string (calling `toString()`).
Then `"function (){return 1}" <= "function (){return 1}"` performs an less or equal comparison on strings, which is `true`.

In `function(){return 1} == function(){return 1}` JavaScript compares the function objects. But because these are different instances, you'll have `false`.

You can check more about equality operator in [this article](http://rainsoft.io/the-legend-of-javascript-equality-operator/).

Comment: Arg, i just found that too. Going to reference yours in my answer. +1

Answer (score -1):

Because it´s always is comparing 1 <= 1, and it´s true. If you compare 1 >= 1 is the same always it´s true. But if you compare 1 > 1 it´s false.

Comment: Sorry, @harsh your question isn´t clear... but i readed the comment below

Comment: This is still wrong, the issue has nothing to do with what the functions are returning (per se) since the functions are not being executed. The comparison is being run on the functions

Comment: @Patty It would be working ask you describe in this case: `(function(){return 1})() <= (function(){return 1})()`